# 2013 Chevy Malibu LT 2.5L

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-injectors, malibu, maf

I saw your message about "don't go looking for trouble..."
I replaced my MAF 1.5 yrs ago along with the intake and exhaust VVT solenoids after codes p0013 p0014 would pop up. It ran beautifully. Then it through up a permanent code so we replaced the O2 sensor on the exhaust manifold. My car now idles a little rough after it idles down... then will die. It mostly does it when it is cold but it hasn't done this in the 4 yrs I've had it. I noticed this morning the fuel smelled a little more rich in my garage (yes the door was open lol) my dad said to put some seafoam in there since there are no codes and it sounds like the injectors might need cleaned. Can you offer some insight on the problem and... is it safe for us to drive 9.5 hours away for a weekend getaway in a couple weeks?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How many miles on the odometer?  Are there a lot of towns along the way on your planned trip?